# getInputStream() is not returning readable information

Tags: java

My homework assignment is to call a .jar from within a java program but I can't get the input stream to return the results into something readable. Here is what I did first:

```
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
System.out.println(in);
```

But that didn't work, and I found some different variation:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
System.out.println(input);
```

But that didn't work either, both scenarios it returned something like this: java.io.BufferedReader@2ce908.  How can I get it to return a readable output?

EDIT: This is a java program receiving the output from another java program.  The program that the user starts is called Translate.java which takes in English words and passes them as command line arguments using the Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Dictionary.jar"+) command.  I was told to use the getInputStream() in Translate.java to receive the output from the Dictionary.java program.

Comment: YOu got the stream but where are you reading from the stream. Add readline()

Comment: Have a read through [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stream is not text; it is a thing that reads a file for you. You have to call `readLine`:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String s = null;
while ((s = input.readLine()) != null) { // it returns null at the end of the file
    System.out.println(s);
}
```